# Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 is getting the wrong address

Tags: server, 20.04, dhcp

After restarting Ubuntu Server 20.04.2, use the wrong IP address. It is registered to DHCP for a MAC address such as this '9f6e852400020000ab117b61e29f5a2058bf'. When I run the command:

> `sudo dhclient -v -r ens160 && sudo dhclient -v ens160`

the server obtains the correct registered IP address. The Server runs on VMware and the network uses only IPv4.

Does anyone know why this is happening and is there a solution to this?

**Edit 19.9.2021:**
Problem isnt solved but I have "solution":

1. install ifupdown

> sudo apt install -y ifupdown

2. edit /etc/network/interfaces

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces 
> auto lo 
> iface lo inet loopback 
> auto eth0 
> iface eth0 inet dhcp 
> post-up dhclient -r && dhclient

3. purge netplan

> sudo apt purge -y netplan.io

4. use

> sudo ifup -a 
> sudo dhclient -r

5. restart network service or reboot
6. delete netplan directory with config files

> sudo rm -vfr /usr/share/netplan /etc/netplan

Maybe before point 4. restart network.

Comment: Can you show us your network configuration file(s)?

Comment: I hope, that this is what you want: 
'network:
ethernets:
ens160:
dhcp4: true
version: 2'

Comment: So you have removed Netplan, and opts for a "non-standard" way (on Ubuntu). I don't think this is a good idea, and neither will it be easier to get support here. Just my thoughts.

Comment: Also in my world, a MAC address has 12 digits, but I may be limited in my knowledge here.

Comment: 2Artur: Yes I know, it is non-standard solution. On Ubuntu 16.4.x LTS the network work fine. On Ubuntu 18.4.x LTS (clear installation)  network work with same problem, but, when I Ubuntu upgrade from 16.4.x LTS to 18.4.x LTS, network work fine. 
Yes I know, that the MAC address has only 12char, and it was surprising me, and i don't understand, why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

[I found solution, when i was reading this article](https://jaylacroix.com/fixing-ubuntu-18-04-virtual-machines-that-fight-over-the-same-ip-address/)